# What is the gradient descent rule using binary cross entropy (BCE) with tanh?

Tags: gradient-descent, activation-function

Similar to [this post](http://How%20to%20implement%20gradient%20descent%20for%20a%20tanh()%20activation%20function%20for%20a%20single%20layer%20perceptron?), I need the gradient descent step of tanh but now with binary cross entropy (BCE).

So we have

$$
\Delta \omega = -\eta \frac{\delta E}{\delta \omega}
$$

Now we have BCE:

$$
E = −(ylog(\hat{y})+(1−y)log(1−\hat{y}))
$$

Considering my output is $\hat{y} = tanh(\omega .x)$, $x$ is my input vector and $y_i$ is the corresponding label here. 
$$
\frac{\delta E}{\delta \omega} = \frac{\delta −(ylog(tanh(wx))+(1−y)log(1−tanh(wx)))}{\delta \omega} 
$$

Now on [this website](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap3.html#the_cross-entropy_cost_function) they do something similar for the normal sigmoid and arrive at (eq 60):

$$
\frac{σ′(z)x}{ σ(z)(1−σ(z))}(σ(z)−y)
$$

Could we use that and continue there? We can get the derivative like [this](https://blogs.cuit.columbia.edu/zp2130/derivative_of_tanh_function/) and get:

$$
\frac{tanh′(wx)x}{tanh(wx)(1−tanh(wx))}(tanh(wx)−y)
\\= \frac{x-xtanh(wx)^2}{tanh(wx)(1−tanh(wx))}(tanh(wx)−y)
\\= \frac{x-x\hat{y}^2}{\hat{y}(1−\hat{y})}(\hat{y}−y)
\\= \frac{(\hat{y} + 1)x(\hat{y} - y)}{\hat{y}}
$$

Wherever I look, I don't find this :)

**Update**

Given the first answer that gives $(1 + \hat{y})(1 - \hat{y})$, we arrive at the same

$$
\frac{tanh′(wx)x}{tanh(wx)(1−tanh(wx))}(tanh(wx)−y)
\\= \frac{x(1 + \hat{y})(1 - \hat{y})}{\hat{y}(1−\hat{y})}(\hat{y}−y)
\\= \frac{(\hat{y} + 1)x(\hat{y} - y)}{\hat{y}}
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let 'a' be the output from an activation function like sigmoid or tanh.

Therefore, the derivative of sigmoid is a*(1-a) whereas the derivative for tanh is (1+a)*(1-a).

Just follow the derivation of sigmoid except replace the derivative of sigmoid with that of tanh.

Comment: So that gives the same outcome. But isn't that problematic when $\hat{y} = 0$ (division by 0)?

Comment: Since you have defined your loss BCE function which can take ground truth values (i.e., $y$) 1 or 0, you would need to use sigmoid function as your activation function to bound your output $\hat{y}$ between 0 and 1. If you still want to use tanh then look at the loss you concur when your $\hat{y} = 0$: it blows to infinity! Therefore using tanh as your activation for the defined form of BCE wouldn't make sense.

Comment: @Roelant Do you still have some doubt?